# IOs-How to handle in app purchase billing?

Tags: xcode, react-native, in-app-purchase, expo

In order to implement in app purchase using expo am using https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases.
I implemented as per the document and i tested it in sandbox mode.what i have did is:

1)Set up in app purchase in appstore.

2)implement the functionality accordingly.

3)Validate receipt with cloud function and return the expiry date.

My question here is is there anything to do in our end regarding the billing?in sandbox mode if it is a fake transaction it didn't ask anything about payment.How it work in production is it differently and need we do anything for managing billing?
Any explanation, suggestions and corrections will be awesome.

My code is:

```
........
if (InAppPurchases.setPurchaseListener) {
        InAppPurchases.setPurchaseListener(({ responseCode, results, errorCode }) => {
            if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.OK) {
                results.forEach(purchase => {
                    if (!purchase.acknowledged) {
                        if (purchase.transactionReceipt) {
                            if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
                                if (!this.flag) {
                                    this.flag = true;
                                    fetch("url", {
                                        method: "POST",
                                        body: JSON.stringify(purchase),
                                        headers: { "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8" }
                                    })
                                        .then(response => {
                                            if (response.ok) {
                                                return response.json();
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .then(json => {
                                            if (json && Object.keys(json).length) {
                                                let subscriptionDetails = {};
                                                subscriptionDetails.subscribed = json.isExpired;
                                                subscriptionDetails.expiry = JSON.parse(json.expiryDate);
                                                subscriptionDetails.inTrialPeriod = json.inTrial;
                                                subscriptionDetails.productId = json.id;
                                                SecureStore.setItemAsync(
                                                    "Subscription",
                                                    JSON.stringify(subscriptionDetails)
                                                )
                                                    .then(() => {
                                                        console.info("subscription Saved:");
                                                        store.dispatch(
                                                            setWsData("isSubscriptionExpired", json.isExpired)
                                                        );
                                                        let expired = json.isExpired;
                                                        store.dispatch(setUiData("isCheckAnalyze", true));
                                                        store.dispatch(setWsData("firstSubscription", false));
                                                        
                                                        this.setState({ checkExpiry: json.isExpired });
                                                        
                                                        if (!expired) {
                                                            InAppPurchases.finishTransactionAsync(purchase, true);
                                                            
                                                            alert("Now you are Subscribed!!");
                                                        } else {
                                                            alert("Expired");
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                    .catch(error =>
                                                        console.error("Cannot save subscription details:", error)
                                                    );
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .catch(err => console.log("error:", err));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What are you expecting to handle about billing? If it works in Sandbox, it will most likely work in Production. It's not your responsibility to bill people's credit cards for the sum you require; that is handled by the storefront.

Comment: that means we dont want to add card,store card,refund any such things in our end?Is the above code is enough?